# Sharing data between apps

Tags: android, data-storage

I'm having 2 apps.

1st app need to store a large string data.
Q. Where should I store this string, that will be acessed by 2nd app.

I'm aware of Data storage schemes in android. 
Do I need to store it in Internal storage or SharedPreferences?
I'm aware of Creating world-readable files is very dangerous.

is there a way to share this string with only 2nd app?

Comment: Create Database in secret folder and access it from both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, sharing data between apps is most safely and conveniently done through content providers.

You can look here for help:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Or here:

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html

With a provider the file remains private to one of the apps, it just provides a way for the other app to access the data. Thus any 3rd party app cannot access the file - they may access the provider instead but that is much less discoverable any you can implement some simple access control if needed.

Comment: if I use content provider then too I need to save it in a File data which need to be world readable to access its content by 2nd app.

Comment: You can back the content provider by any means of storing data, would it be an SQLite database or a flatfile. Note that sharing a file (even making it worldreadable) through a content provider is way safer than without one.

Comment: I believe storing a large string will be ok in file then SQLite. Can u please explain how it is safer using content provider then SharedPreferences?

Comment: Consider using a Document Provider:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: I'm clear with the safety factor in content provider so I'll go with content provider